# How to read my own installed CA Certificate from iPhone/iPad device in Swift (2.0)?

Tags: objective-c, swift

i Want to read my own installed certificate CN name and Expiry date from app. How to get list of certificates from KeyStore and read name in Swift 2.0?

Note :- Certificate is installed under => Device management =Digital Work Space

Can any one help on this?